# Run a task from inside a task. (watch)

Tags: gulp

Regarding this gulp task.
How could I make it so that whenever this task runs (because it uses watch), then another task would run too, let's call the other task scripts2.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
return gulp.src(src + '/**/*.js', {read: false}) // no need of reading file because browserify does
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(watch(src + '/**/*.js')) // WATCH
    // transform file objects using gulp-tap plugin
    .pipe(tap(function (file) {
        // replace file contents with browserify's bundle stream
        file.contents = browserify(file.path, {debug: true}).transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015']}).bundle();
    }))
    // transform streaming contents into buffer contents (because gulp-sourcemaps does not support streaming contents)
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you must be using `gulp-watch`? One thing you can do is use gulp's built-in `watch` for this instead, set to run two tasks when a change is detected in your watched files. In the following example, you'd run `gulp watcher`

```
gulp.task('scripts2', function() {
    console.log('hello world')
});

// I've left 'scripts' identical to what you gave us, except for dropping the watch pipe
//
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(src + '/**/*.js', { read: false }) // no need of reading file because browserify does
        .pipe(plumber())
        // transform file objects using gulp-tap plugin
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
            // replace file contents with browserify's bundle stream
            file.contents = browserify(file.path, { debug: true }).transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015'] }).bundle();
        }))
        // transform streaming contents into buffer contents (because gulp-sourcemaps does not support streaming contents)
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('watcher', function() {
    gulp.watch(src + '/**/*.js', ['scripts','scripts2'])
});
```